# Are there exotic open manifolds in dimensions >4?

Tags: differential-topology

This seems like a question for which there should either be easy-ish examples or an easy-ish proof of "no", but I can't seem to find a reference.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “exotic”?  Do you mean you want noncompact manifolds that have more than one smooth structure?

Comment: Yes exactly that

Comment: There are definitely many examples.  I’m not posting this as an answer since I suspect you’ll get much more complete ones from real experts, but one construction I like a lot is in here: Farrell, F. T. (1-SUNY2); Jones, L. E. (1-SUNYS)
Nonuniform hyperbolic lattices and exotic smooth structures. 
J. Differential Geom. 38 (1993), no. 2, 235–261.

Comment: An in-depth answer would be exciting, but this definitely answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: There are experts on surgery theory on here that can probably point you to much easier constructions.  But Farrell-Jones have a lot of beautiful papers that explore how exotic smooth structures interact with geometry, and one can learn a lot by flipping through their papers.

Comment: If $M, N$ are closed smooth manifolds such that $M\times\mathbb R$, $N\times\mathbb R$ are diffeomorphic, then $M, N$ are are h-cobordant. Closed simply connected h-cobordant  manifolds of dimension $\ge 5$ are diffeomorphic (more, generally this is true if "simply connected" is replaced by vanishing of the Whitehead group of the fundamental group). For example if $M$ is an exotic sphere or an exotic torus of dimension $\ge 5$, and $N$ is the standard sphere/torus of the same dimension as $M$, then $M\times\mathbb R$, $N\times\mathbb R$ aren't diffeomorphic.